# What's the meaning of oscI(fn-f)?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

[image]

I haven't seen the form of osc$_I(f_n-f)$.I expect your explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One often defines the **oscillation** of a function on an interval to be the difference between its supremum on the interval and its infimum on the interval.

If $|f| \leq M$, then the oscillation of $f$ on $I$ is at most $2M$.  That's what's going on here.

Comment: Could you give me a detailed explanation frome the  fifth line from the bottom to the end?

Comment: @parkning: Take a look at $\S$ 13.2.1 of http://math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf.  The result you are interested in is proved there; maybe you'll find the exposition easier to understand.

Comment: But okay: the expression with the sum of the oscillations is just the difference between an upper sum and a lower sum for the same partition.  By **Darboux's Criterion**, $f$ is integrable if this difference can be made arbitrarily small.  (See Chapter 8 of the notes linked to above!)

Answer (score 2):

It is the [oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_%28mathematics%29) over the set $I$ (in this case an interval) of the function $f_n-f$.

This is defined as the diameter of the set $(f_n-f)(I) = \{f_n(x)-f(x) \mathrel| x \in I\}$. As the name suggests, it measures how much the function varies over the set.